# Teradata: varchar to timestamp 2

Tags: sql, teradata

how to convert VARCHAR value like `MM.DD.YYYY hh:mm:ss` to TIMESTAMP?

Example:

```
SEL Cast ( '10.16.2018 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP Format 'mm.dd.yyyy hh:mi:ss')
```

Returns `6760: Invalid timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Teradata FORMAT a blank must be specefied as `B`

```
SELECT Cast ( '10.16.2018 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'mm.dd.yyyyBhh:mi:ss')
```

This returns a TIMESTAMP(6) (similar to TO_TIMESTAMP), but you can change the precision:

```
SELECT Cast ( '10.16.2018 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'mm.dd.yyyyBhh:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/lItshZTOCQa4HCpVsFcQBw) function.

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('10.16.2018 00:00:00', 'mm.dd.yyyy hh:mi:ss')
```